# $fg \in L^1$ for every $f \in L^2$ implies $g \in L^2$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Suppose that $f g$ is in $L^1([a,b])$ for every $f$ in $L^2([a,b])$, I understand that this implies that $g$ is in $L^2([a,b])$. Is this assertion true and, if so, how do I prove it?

This question was set as an exercise in the book *An Introduction to Lebesgue Integration and Fourier Series* by H. Wilcox and D. Myers. It should actually be an "easy" exercise as no hint is provided and its proof should not require more than basic concepts on the $L^2$ function space.

I would expect that the proof starts by assuming that $g$ is not in $L^2$ and then continues by showing that, for a suitable choice of $f$ in $L^2([a,b])$, the product $f g$ is not in $L^1([a,b])$. But I am unable to arrive at a complete proof.

I have seen a more general version of this question [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091522/fg-in-l1-for-all-g-in-lq-longrightarrow-f-in-lp) but its focus  is slightly different and the explanation provided there relies on the notion of -finite measure spaces with which I am not familiar. I would therefore be grateful if someone could re-cast the reasoning in that post to more closely match the specific case raised in my question (or perhaps provide a simpler proof, if it exists).

Comment: No simpler proof. If you don't understand the proof in the link you can ask the answerer for more details.

Comment: If $\sigma$-finiteness is a problem to you then you can simply google the definition. Your space is $[a,b]$ which is a finite measure space so you need not even bother with that.